# Resizing of an image isn't behaving 'normal'

Tags: html, css

I would like to resize the arrow (right, gray) to resize and behave like the logo (middle). When you adjust the browser window to the left or right, the gray arrow is resizing fine. But when you make the browser window higher or taller (up/down adjustment), the arrow can be placed along the right side of the screen.

It would be nice if the arrow could have his current place fixed and behave / resize like the (sober) logo in the middle of the page.

The problem is located in the class: .ArrowUp.

You can find the whole website here --> https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/61634717/Website.zip

```
#HomePageLogo {
height: auto; /*120*/
width: auto; /*450*/
text-align:center;

padding-top:19%;
padding-right:35%;
padding-bottom:15%;
padding-left:35%;
}

body {
/*background:#000000; -- Test achtergrond -- */
/*background-image:url('../Pictures/HomePage/Background_HomePage1.jpg');*/

background: #2E2E2E url('../Pictures/HomePage/Background_HomePage1.jpg') no-repeat top left;
background-size:cover;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
width:auto;
height:0px;
}

img {
max-width:100%;
height:auto;
}

.ArrowUp {
position:absolute;
top:53%;/* ?? */
right:1%;
bottom:0%; /* ?? */
left:88%;
}
```

Kind of new to html & css. Any help or improvements are welcome.

Comment: Do you want the arrow to always be centered with the background-image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if this helps: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/886568/Website_WaldoToelen.zip

You were missing the part where the arrow needs to be in the same container as the "SOBER" image, in order to get it to be absolutely positioned along.